# PHP error reporting: Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

When I get a PHP error it comes up with a 500 internal server error page. I would like it to display the fatal error. I have spent literally days trying to get it to display the proper error. Here is what I have tried so far:

1) Editing the wp-config.php file as described here: https://help.massivedynamic.co/hc/en-us/articles/115000572108-How-to-enable-WordPress-error-reporting. I tried both the option to display the error and create logs.

2) Access Plesk and making changes according to https://support.managed.com/kb/a1937/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-in-plesk-11.aspx. This seems to change the user.ini file to read: `[PHP]
display_errors=on
error_log="d:\Plesk\VHOSTS\[MYDOMAIN]\php.log.resources"
log_errors=on`. I have also tried changing the directory here manually but to no avail.

3) Adding various assortment of code in the header of the page. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); echo "aaa"; ob_flush();` being one of many.

Can anyone suggest what more I could try?

Thank you.

Comment: 500 is not a PHP error, its a server error. Have a look at your .htaccess, it probaly has an error.

Comment: 500 error means your code is having the error, so go through the code, and turn on wp debug to true. it will show errors and warnings in the page

Comment: @ Jelmergu The error only occurs when I change the php file. I do not have a htaccess file.

Comment: @Exprator sorry I wasnt clear: My issue is that I cannot view the error. I am trying to turn on the error log.

Comment: but generally turning on the debug in wpconfig displays all the errors, is there any suppression you have done not to show errors?

Comment: It is not possible to change the configuration regarding error reporting at runtime ... if your script doesn’t _run_ to begin with due to syntax errors. So any setting in the WP configuration or trying to call ini_set/error_reporting are of course fruitless in that situation. // Are you really using plesk on a windows machine here? Create a script that contains nothing but a call to phpinfo, upload that to the base directory, call it in the browser and check if the settings you tried to make had any effect or not.

Comment: @CBroe It is Plesk on a dedicated windows server yes. phpinfo returns d:\Plesk\VHOSTS\[maindomain]\[subdomain]\php.log.resources

Comment: And what does it say for error_reporting?

Comment: d:\Plesk\VHOSTS[maindomain][subdomain]\php.log.resou‌​rces: no value

Answer (score 1):

a 500 is a code error, or a server system error.

you can several things you can do to debug:

- make sure you have full error reporting on in your php.ini (or at the top of the script)
- try a simpler bit of code to make sure its not the server throwing the error.
- use [xdebug](https://xdebug.org) to step through the code until you find where its failing.  Then use a try/catch to try to find out what the error actually was.
- look in the server logs if you have access to them.
- write proper unit tests (you do write tests yes?) for the sections of code you are using.  Often its easier to isolate a problem with a unit test than it is when that code is part of a much larger application.
- use echo's and var_dumps to try to see where the code is falling over.

full error reporting.  Put this at the top of your script if you dont have access to php.ini:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I overestimate what debug information can be retrieved? For example, I have a problem with imagejpeg($thumb, $imageDirectory, 20); This cases a 500 internal error. I would like to know why e.g. is it an issue with image or with saving to the server.

Comment: haha so theres no way to get any information on why that failed? Or even to have that line in the code indicated?

Comment: there is, but it depends on what threw the 500.  if the server threw it before the php engine ran its opcode, then you wont get one.  if php threw it because of a memory error, you wont get one either.  Ive updated my answer with the line to turn on full error reporting in php

Answer (score 0):

You can view the error by accessing the Apache error log file for your virtual host.

If your virtual host is called example.com, then your error log file should be located at /var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/error.log

Answer (score -1):

Search your wordpress root for error_log file. Depending from your setup, it is there, or on your wamp stack log folder. 
Like already commented, 500 is not a PHP error but a server error, so you can't get it printed out with PHP.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I am completely misunderstanding it. I notice it happens when there is a syntax error in the php. Is it not possible to debug this type of error?

Comment: this is completely wrong.  A 500 runtime error can be thrown by php in the event of syntax errors or other problems.  With error reporting on you can get it to tell you what the problem is.